# Ionic start cannot download binary

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to create my first ionic project but it failed. The error message:

> Downloading binary from
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/darwin-x64-64_binding.node
>
> Cannot download
>   "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/darwin-x64-64_binding.node"
>
> HTTP error 404 Not Found

Node Version - v10.3.0 / Ionic Version - 3.20.0

[image]
[image][image]

This error made me cant run my project on the browser. when I command ionic serve. It seems lost some file. The error message:

> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Lester/Desktop/newproject/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts'

Issues related 
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2416 
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13677

But I didn't see good solution there. Should i downgrade my node version or download the file manually? But what's the procedure? Anyone know how to solve this?

This happen after i set the proxy to GitHub.com:8080 and 1234. it stuck at running command

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need to downgrade your node version to 8

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time. 
My OS: ubuntu 18.04
i used "sudo n 8(node version number)"